# Provide an HTML page with JS with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to serve an html page with a linked js script using node.js and express.
This is the server that provide the page:

```
var express = require("express");
var app2 = express();
app2.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('./index.html');
});
app2.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
```

and this is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/codice.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see I have two js scripts in my js folder but they are not loaded when I launch the page. What can I do?

Comment: Your `app2` Express object is only set to respond to GET requests for `/`, whereas you're expecting it to respond to arbitrary GET requests (specifically for `/js/socket.io.js` and `/js/codice.js`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would normally do is place any public resources (JavaScript files, CSS files, images etc) in a directory (Express names it *public* by default) and then use the [`express.static` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) in your `app.configure` call:

```
app.configure(function () {
    // Various other middleware functions...
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
});
```

This effectively runs a static file server which will return any file inside the *public* directory. Currently, your browser is making a request for your JS files, but the Express server doesn't know what to do with them. They will eventually time out.

If you generate the initial state of your app with the global `express` executable (available if you installed Express via npm globally), it will set most of this up for you.